# can't use a bounce list as suppression list in Marketing Cloud Send Email Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, suppressionlist

I have created a list from a send job bounce records. I used Copy All to create the list and was able to only save it under My Lists (didn't have any other folder option).
I need to use this list as a suppression list in my send but can't choose it if I choose a Targeted Audience from my filtered data extensions. It only works if the Target is also from My Lists.
[image]
[image]
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the suppression data into a DE. Export/import from list into DE or query the data from list into a suppression DE via automation studio

Comment: Hi, 
thanks, sorry for the late reply. what's the standard method for "Put the suppression data into a DE. Export/import from list into DE " , I couldn't find an easy way to export a list and import to a DE without exporting it to csv, create a DE, import the csv in to the DE. Is there a better way?
It's normally a one off thing so no need for automation. For example you do a send and then you want to exclude those from your next send. How would you go about it?

Comment: unfortunately only alternative is to use SQL and query the lists